# How to understand a recursive function call for large inputs

Tags: c, recursion

The result of the following code is 0,1,2,0, I totally understand after writing explicitly every call. But I wonder whether there is an easier method to understand what the recursive function want to realize and find the result faster? I mean we can't write all the call if a=1000.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(int);
typedef int (*pf) (int, int);
int proc(pf, int, int);

 int main()
{
int a=3;
fun(a);
return 0;
}
void fun(int n)
{
     if(n > 0)
    {
         fun(--n);
         printf("%d,", n);
         fun(--n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through it.. try printing `n` before and after.

Comment: @staticx I know we can find the result by steppint through it, but what if the number is big and we can't step through it? say a=1000? we could test it on a pc, but what if it is in an interview?

Comment: Looks like https://oeis.org/A035614.

Comment: I doubt you would get a thousand elements to examine but if you had to, if you were able to intelligently explain the code I am sure the interviewer would give you a break and not make you step through it a thousand times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't *"what does this do?"* but *"how do I understand recursive functions for large values?"*.

Recursion is a great tool for certain kinds of problems. If, for some reason, you ever had to print that sequence of numbers, the above code would be a good way to solve the problem. Recursion is also used in contexts where you have a recursive structure (like a tree or a list) or are dealing with recursive input, like parsers.

You might see the code for a recursive function and think "what does this do?" but it's more likely that the opposite will happen: you will find a problem that you need to solve by writing a program. With experience you will learn to see which problems require a recursive solution, and that's a skill you must develop as a programmer.

The principle of recursion is that you perform a [usually simple] function repeatedly. So to understand a recursive function you usually need to understand only one step, and how to repeat it.

With the above code you don't necessarily need to answer "what output does this code give" but instead "how does it work, and what process does the code follow". You can do both on paper. By stepping through the algorithm you can usually gain insight into what it does. One factor that complicates this example is that it isn't [tail-call recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion). This means you must do more work to understand the program.

To 'understand' any program you don't necessarily need to be able to simulate it and calculate the output, and the same applies here.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add some debug statements to understand it a little better. This is the result of the if statements I added to track through it:

```
start program
before if, n is = 3
before fun call, n is = 3
before if, n is = 2
before fun call, n is = 2
before if, n is = 1
before fun call, n is = 1
before if, n is = 0
printing = 0
before if, n is = -1
after second fun call, n is = -1
printing = 1
before if, n is = 0
after second fun call, n is = 0
printing = 2
before if, n is = 1
before fun call, n is = 1
before if, n is = 0
printing = 0
before if, n is = -1
after second fun call, n is = -1
after second fun call, n is = 1
end program
```